# Sum of child rows from different table with join

Tags: mysql

```
Table 1 - 
    i_rec_id 
    i_parent_id
    i_type

Table 2 -
    i_rec_id
    i_ref_wbs_id
    vc_plan
```

Table 1: If there is any parent for row then i_parent_id contains i_rec_id of that row,

i_ref_wbs_id is foreign key of tabel 1 i_rec_id.

Question: I want to select all records but if i_type is 1 then it should show sum of vc_plan of its child rows vc_plan

```
Sample Record :

Table 1 -  
i_rec_id     i_parent_id   i_type
1             NULL          1
2             1             2
3             1             2
4             NULL          1
5             1             3
6             4             2

Table 2 
i_rec_id     i_ref_wbs_id   vc_plan
10             1             NULL
21             2             2
31             3             2
42             4             NULL
56             5             3
62             6             2
```

Expected Output:

```
i_rec_id     i_parent_id   i_type   vc_plan
1             NULL          1        7
2             1             2        2
3             1             2        2
4             NULL          1        2
5             1             3        3
6             4             2        2
```

Comment: provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: And the expected output would be ?

Comment: question from the given data how the sum becomes 7 for `i_rec_id = 1` ?

Comment: Please check i_parent_id for i_rec_id 2,3,5   (  parent , child relationship )

Comment: Added an answer, let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

That's a kind of complicated calculation.
Here is one approach, but there could be some better way as well, which I am not able to think of now.

```
select 
t1.*,
if(t1.i_type = 1 , sum(t3.vc_plan),t3.vc_plan) as vc_plan  
from table1 t1 
left join table1 t2 on t2.i_parent_id = t1.i_rec_id 
left join table2 t3 on t3.i_ref_wbs_id = t2.i_rec_id 
or t3.i_ref_wbs_id = t1.i_rec_id 
group by t1.i_rec_id ;
```

Here is the test case with the data set provided in the question and the expected output

```
mysql> select * from table1 ;
+----------+-------------+--------+
| i_rec_id | i_parent_id | i_type |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|        1 |        NULL |      1 |
|        2 |           1 |      2 |
|        3 |           1 |      2 |
|        4 |        NULL |      1 |
|        5 |           1 |      3 |
|        6 |           4 |      2 |
+----------+-------------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2;
+----------+--------------+---------+
| i_rec_id | i_ref_wbs_id | vc_plan |
+----------+--------------+---------+
|       10 |            1 |    NULL |
|       21 |            2 |       2 |
|       31 |            3 |       2 |
|       42 |            4 |    NULL |
|       56 |            5 |       3 |
|       62 |            6 |       2 |
+----------+--------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 
    -> t1.*,
    -> if(t1.i_type = 1 , sum(t3.vc_plan),t3.vc_plan) as vc_plan  
    -> from table1 t1 
    -> left join table1 t2 on t2.i_parent_id = t1.i_rec_id 
    -> left join table2 t3 on t3.i_ref_wbs_id = t2.i_rec_id 
    -> or t3.i_ref_wbs_id = t1.i_rec_id 
    -> group by t1.i_rec_id ;
+----------+-------------+--------+---------+
| i_rec_id | i_parent_id | i_type | vc_plan |
+----------+-------------+--------+---------+
|        1 |        NULL |      1 |       7 |
|        2 |           1 |      2 |       2 |
|        3 |           1 |      2 |       2 |
|        4 |        NULL |      1 |       2 |
|        5 |           1 |      3 |       3 |
|        6 |           4 |      2 |       2 |
+----------+-------------+-----

---+---------+

6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not sure I got your point, I have added a test case in to the answer from your given data set and expected out put.

Comment: Result is different what you showed , for vc_plan show ( for each row respectively ):  9  - 2 -2 - NULL - 3 -2